# Function to remove columns with max value less than a given value,

Tags: r, max

I'm doing initial data clean up with 34,000 columns in a dataframe and in order to do that, i have to remove columns whose max value is less than 2.

I'm clueless as to how to remove columns with maxvalue less than 2 but for just getting max values, I tried creating a function as below without converting data with is.numeric:

```
protein <- is.numeric(protein)
#a: 
colMax <- function(data) sapply(data, max, na.rm = TRUE)
colMax(protein)
```

I got the max not meaningful for factors error, which is why i used the is.numeric function to convert all data to numeric form. despite doing that I still am not getting the desired result. When running the function I got 0 as a result rather than a list of max values for each column.

Why am i getting 0 for my max function?How do I setup a function that can generate max values for each column and remove any columns whose max values are less than 2? Would I need 2 separate functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way using `dplyr` to select columns where `max` value is greater than equal to 2. Assuming, we want to test for all the columns and all those columns are of class `factor`. Using @Maurits data

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  #Convert column from factor to numeric
  mutate_all(~as.numeric(as.character(.))) %>%
  #Select column whose max value is greater than equal to 2 
  select_if(~max(., na.rm = TRUE) >= 2)


#   V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
#1   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#2   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#3   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#4   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#5   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#6   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#7   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#8   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#9   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#10  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
```

Instead of `max`, we can also use `any`

```
df %>%
  mutate_all(~as.numeric(as.character(.))) %>% 
  select_if(~any(. >= 2))
```

You say that you have 34000 columns. Do you want to check for greater than 2 condition for all the columns? Are all the columns `factors` ? The above code checks for all the columns and selects the one which do not satisfy the condition. If you want to do this on selected columns (not all), you might need to subset data, select those column and then apply the code.

---

In base R, we can also use `colSums` after converting the data from factor to numeric

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
df[, colSums(df >= 2) > 0]
```

Comment: No, I'm missing a 6 in my # of columns, its 364000 columns - some are factors, some aren't. Using lapply is working but with so much data, its taking too long to process. Would the above methods be any faster?

Comment: @Heena I haven't tested it but `colSums` approach should be faster.

Comment: thank you, i realized I was missing the parameter stringasfactors=False and that was causing the huge delay in processing. But once fixed it all worked out.

Answer (score 1):

You were nearly there.

Since you don't provide reproducible sample data let's first create some minimal sample data

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(1:10, each = 10), ncol = 10))
df
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
#1   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#2   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#3   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#4   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#5   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#6   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#7   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#8   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#9   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
```

We now would like to keep only those columns where the `max` value is >2; we can do this using `sapply`

```
df[sapply(df, function(x) max(x, na.rm = T) > 2)]
#   V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
#1   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#2   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#3   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#4   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#5   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#6   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#7   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#8   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#9   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#10  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
```

Explanation: `sapply` loops over the columns of the `data.frame` `df` and returns a `logical` vector (with as many entries as there are columns in `df`).

---

Or we can use `pmax` with `apply`

```
df[apply(pmax(df) > 2, 2, all)]
```

giving the same result. The difference to the first method is that `pmax` returns a `matrix` on which we operate column-wise with `apply(..., MARGIN = 2, ...)`.

Comment: thanks, my datatype issue still exists though. Running the above code with converting my data using is.numeric  gives me the result as logical(0). Am I doing something wrong with my data conversion?

Comment: @Heena - `as.numeric` doesn't work on the whole dataset all at once. Something like `protein[] <- lapply(protein, as.numeric)` will be needed to overwrite the original data.

Comment: It's difficult to help without representative sample data. So I need to speculate here. Take a look at my example. `data` needs to be a `data.frame`, not a column. Perhaps your conversion issue stems from the fact that you're trying to convert a `factor` to a `numeric` vector, in which case try `data$your_column <- as.numeric(as.character(df$your_column))`.

Comment: @Heena I've made an edit to my post to include some further explanations. Please take a look.